# Multiple export classes from same require(jsfile)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm currently designing an application and have some classes I'm extending. Below is a brief sample code of how it looks **today**, as well as where I **want to go** (aka one file, multiple classes and export them + consume them in **main.js** - or any other)..

---

**TODAY**

**main.js**

```
const UrgentTask = require('./urgentTask');
const Task = require('./task');
var ut = new UrgentTask({ name: "Some task", priority: "URGENT" });
var nt = new Task({ name: "Normal task" });

console.log(ut.toString());
console.log(nt.toString());
```

**task.js**

```
'use strict'

class Task {
    constructor(data) {
        this.name = data.name;
        this.completed = false;
    }

    complete() {
        console.log('completing task: ' + this.name);
        this.completed = true;
    }

    save() {
        console.log('Saving task: ' + this.name);
    }

    toString() {
        return this.name + ' ' + this.completed;
    }
}

module.exports = Task;
```

**urgentTask.js**

```
'use strict' 

var Task = require('./task');

// Decorate "TASK"
class UrgentTask extends Task {
    constructor(data) {
        super(data);
        this.priority = data.priority;
    }

    toString() {
        return `[${this.priority}] ${super.toString()}`;
    }
}

module.exports = UrgentTask;
```

---

**WHAT I WOULD LIKE**

**main.js**

```
const { Task, UrgentTask } = require('./task');
var ut = new UrgentTask({ name: "Some task", priority: "URGENT" });
var nt = new Task({ name: "Normal task" });

console.log(ut.toString());
console.log(nt.toString());
```

**task.js**

=> this would ideally export the two classes, but I don't know how to?
What I already tried:

```
module.exports = Task;
module.exports = UrgentTask;
```

But this blows up in node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> WHAT I WOULD LIKE
>
> ```
> const { Task, UrgentTask } = require('./task');
> ```

That's a *destructuring* assignment, which assigns object properties to discrete bindings (constants, in this case).

So you need to export an object:

ES2015+ syntax (but using Node modules, not ES2015 modules):

```
module.exports = {Task, UrgentTask};
```

ES5 and earlier syntax:

```
module.exports = {Task: Task, UrgentTask: UrgentTask};
```

Actually, by default, `exports` already *is* an object so you can also do this:

```
module.exports.Task = Task;
module.exports.UrgentTask = UrgentTask;
```

But replacing it with a new object is fine too.

Simple non-Require example:

```js
function getMyStuff() {
  class Task { }
  class UrgentTask extends Task { }
  return {Task, UrgentTask};
}

const {Task, UrgentTask} = getMyStuff();
const ut = new UrgentTask();
console.log(ut instanceof UrgentTask); // true
console.log(ut instanceof Task);       // true
```

NodeJS example:

`mymodule.js`:

```
class Task { }
class UrgentTask extends Task { }
module.exports = {Task, UrgentTask};
```

`myapp.js`:

```
const {Task, UrgentTask} = require("./mymodule.js");
const ut = new UrgentTask();
console.log(ut instanceof UrgentTask); // true
console.log(ut instanceof Task);       // true
```

Comment: Thanks. However when I use the ES2015+ using Node modules as you suggested (as well as following the example in your NodeJS example), I get a node error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" on the first "{" after the keyword "const". Using node 4.6.1. Am I doing something wrong then? Or can't node handle it and should I use "use strict" in main.js as well maybe?

Comment: @YvesSchelpe: Node v4 doesn't support destructuring assignment, not even in strict mode. Node v6 does (and basically everything else in ES2015 except modules, as of the current v6.9.1).

Comment: ok, upgrading it is then :)
I saw it being used in electron, but my local machine still has node 4.6 it seems.. 
EDIT: After upgrade it runs as expected, phew. This is a lot easier. Thanks for the elaborate explenation, it has given me even more insight now @T.J. Crowder ! A+